# uploadify scriptData problem

Tags: uploadify

I'm having problems with scriptData on uploadify, I'm pretty sure the config syntax is fine but whatever I do, scriptData is not passed to the upload script.

I tested in both FF and Chrome with flash v. Shockwave Flash 9.0 r31

This is the config:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id_file').uploadify({
        'uploader'          : '/media/filebrowser/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'            : '/admin/filebrowser/upload_file/',
        'scriptData'        : {'session_key': 'e1b552afde044bdd188ad51af40cfa8e'},
        'checkScript'       : '/admin/filebrowser/check_file/',
        'cancelImg'         : '/media/filebrowser/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'auto'              : false,
        'folder'            : '',
        'multi'             : true,
        'fileDesc'          : '*.html;*.py;*.js;*.css;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff;*.mp3;*.mp4;*.wav;*.aiff;*.midi;*.m4p;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpeg;*.mpg;*.avi;*.rm;*.pdf;*.doc;*.rtf;*.txt;*.xls;*.csv;',
        'fileExt'           : '*.html;*.py;*.js;*.css;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png;*.tif;*.tiff;*.mp3;*.mp4;*.wav;*.aiff;*.midi;*.m4p;*.mov;*.wmv;*.mpeg;*.mpg;*.avi;*.rm;*.pdf;*.doc;*.rtf;*.txt;*.xls;*.csv;',
        'sizeLimit'         : 10485760,
        'scriptAccess'      : 'sameDomain',
        'queueSizeLimit'    : 50,
        'simUploadLimit'    : 1,
        'width'             : 300,
        'height'            : 30,
        'hideButton'        : false,
        'wmode'             : 'transparent',
        translations        : {
                              browseButton: 'BROWSE',
                              error: 'An Error occured',
                              completed: 'Completed',
                              replaceFile: 'Do you want to replace the file',
                              unitKb: 'KB',
                              unitMb: 'MB'
        }
    });
    $('input:submit').click(function(){
        $('#id_file').uploadifyUpload();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I checked that other values (file name) are passed correctly but session_key is not.

This is the decorator code from django-filebrowser, you can see it checks for 
request.POST.get('session_key'), the problem is that request.POST is empty.

```
def flash_login_required(function):
    """
    Decorator to recognize a user  by its session.
    Used for Flash-Uploading.
    """

    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            engine = __import__(settings.SESSION_ENGINE, {}, {}, [''])
        except:
            import django.contrib.sessions.backends.db
            engine = django.contrib.sessions.backends.db
        print request.POST
        session_data = engine.SessionStore(request.POST.get('session_key'))
        user_id = session_data['_auth_user_id']
        # will return 404 if the session ID does not resolve to a valid user
        request.user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution without using `scriptData`. You can pass your data by passing through your URL:

```
$("#image_upload1").uploadify({
            'method':'POST',
            'buttonText':'Select',
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
            'swf':'<?php echo base_url()?>resources/flash/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader':'<?php echo site_url('item/update_item_images/'.$picid[0]); ?>',
            'width': 40,
            'multi':false,
            'onUploadComplete':function(file)
            {
                $('.original').hide();
                $('#image1').attr('style','background-image:url("../resources/uploads/<?php echo $id;?>/'+file.name+'");background-size: 140px 119px;');
                $('#hidden_img_value1').attr('value',file.name)
            }
        });
```

Here I pass the value `$picid[0]` in uploader. This data you can access in your controller.

Comment: Ingenious. The scriptData thing is always such a pain with uploadify but this totally works around the whole stupid problem. Wish Ronniesan would fix this or write some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

@Jimbo after removing inverted comma (') ,then also the value is not reciving in controller.

```
$("#image_upload1").uploadify({
            'method':'POST',
            'buttonText':'Select',
            'fileTypeDesc' : 'Image Files',
            'fileTypeExts' : '*.gif; *.jpg; *.png',
            'swf':'<?php echo base_url()?>resources/flash/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader':'<?php echo site_url('item/update_item_image1')?>',
            'width': 40,
            'multi':false,
            'scriptData':{id:'<?=$picid[0]?>'},
            'onUploadComplete':function(file)
            {
                //alert(response);
                $('.original').hide();
                $('#image1').attr('style','background-image:url("../resources/uploads/18/'+file.name+'")');
                $('#hidden_img_value1').attr('value',file.name)
            }
        });
```

Comment: i found a solution.we can use formdata for example :-                         'formData'      : {'someKey':'someValue','someOtherKey' : 1},

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but are you sure it's a session_key problem?

I had an authentication problem with filebrowser+uploadify but the problem was not the session_key but that the site was protected by a HTTP digest authentication set in Apache and, although session_key was sent fine, uploadify does not send the HTTP authentication headers.

Is your *web server* requiring any form of authentication?

Comment: No, it uses the standard django authentication for the admin panel (cookie based).

Answer (score 0):

I had a a similar problem passing script data in the past. Removing the inverted comma (') around  the key in the key/value pairs fixed my problem

Instead of:

```
'scriptData'        : {'session_key': 'e1b552afde044bdd188ad51af40cfa8e'},
```

Use:

```
'scriptData'        : {session_key: 'e1b552afde044bdd188ad51af40cfa8e'},
```

(useful Uploadify post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399654/oncomplete-and-oncompleteall-events-failing-to-fire-when-using-uploadify))