# Uploadify Hanging at random on 100%

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am using [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) to enable my users to upload images via my web application.

The problem I am having is that every now and then (at what appears to be random) when the progress bar reaches 100% it 'hangs' and does nothing.

I was wondering if any developers familiar with uploadify may have any idea how to solve this? I am in desperate need of some help.

Here is my front-end code:

```
<javascript>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#uploadify").uploadify({
  'uploader'       : 'javascripts/uploadify.swf',
  'script'         : 'upload-file2.php',
  'cancelImg'      : 'css/images/cancel.png',
  'folder'         : 'uploads/personal_images/' + profileOwner,
  'queueID'        : 'fileQueue',
  'auto'           : true,
  'multi'          : true,
  'fileDesc'       : 'Image files',
     'fileExt'        : '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
  'sizeLimit'      : '2097152',
  'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data)
  {
   processPersonalImage(fileObj.name);
   arrImgNames.push(fileObj.name);
   showUploadedImages(true);
   document.getElementById("photos").style.backgroundImage = "url('css/images/minicam.png')";
  },
  'onAllComplete'  : function()
  {
     completionMessage(arrFailedNames);
     document.getElementById("displayImageButton").style.display = "inline";
     document.getElementById("photos").style.backgroundImage = "url('css/images/minicam.png')";
  },
  'onCancel'  : function()
  {
     arrImgNames.push(fileObj.name);
     arrFailedNames.push(fileObj.name);
     showUploadedImages(false);
  },
  'onError'  : function()
  {
     arrImgNames.push(fileObj.name);
     arrFailedNames.push(fileObj.name);
     showUploadedImages(false);
  }
 });
});
</javascript>
```

And server side:

```
 if (!empty($_FILES)) 
 {
  //Get user ID from the file path for use later..
  $userID = getIdFromFilePath($_REQUEST['folder'], 3); 
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(getRecentAlbum($userID, "photo_album_personal"));
  $subFolderName = $row['pk'];
     //Prepare target path / file..
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
  $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/'.$subFolderName.'/';
  $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
  //Move uploaded file from temp directory to new folder
  move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
  //Now add a record to DB to reflect this personal image..
  if(file_exists($targetFile))
  {
   //add photo record to DB
   $directFilePath = $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/'.$subFolderName.'/' . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
   addPersonalPhotoRecordToDb($directFilePath, $row['pk']);
  }
  echo "1";
  die(true);
 }
```

thanks for any help!!

Comment: use stack overflows code feature to make code more readable

Answer (score 2):

this seems like a php error.
I'd use  Fiddler or a similar problem to view the php response or similar.
Check your php error logs, they might shed some light.

Comment: Heya,

   I really appreciated your response so thankyou. Fiddler you say? I have not heard of that so I will google it up and let you know how I get on :)

With regards to error logs, I am using cheapish hosting (Hostgator) and I dont think I have access.

Comment: Basically, your code never reaches 'echo "1"'. You can echo out breakpoints along the way in your code, and use Firebug to see the results. I've run into this before and you just have to do some old-school debugging until you find the error in your code.

Comment: Wow thats seriously helpful Jnunn, I will try that first thing in the morning. Where in firebug do you see the server replys? Im used to watching outgoing get/post request

Comment: Hey guys,

   I am not seeing any response from the PHP file (shown above) in firebug, am I missing something?

Comment: +1 this is the most likely case. If all else fails, try writing the breakpoints into a log file. Also, make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` turned on so you actually see the error messages.

Comment: Hi pekka thanks for your reponse.

Could you explain a little about what breakpoints are, im un-familir with the term.

Also with error reporting, where are the errors written to?

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem some time ago with Uploadify (using ASP.Net MVC though) - but you will definitely find some useful info regarding the Uploadify event handling and behaviour in the answer posted! Its available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399654/oncomplete-and-oncompleteall-events-failing-to-fire-when-using-uploadify)

Comment: HI Jimbo I really appreciate your input. I tried putting "echo 1" right at the top of the script so it would be returned by the script regardless of how far down the script got, but still getting files hanging at random.

Ive also tried using firebug to see what the php file returns, but im seeing nothing in the response.

Im at a total loss :(

Comment: you wont be able to see the php response with firebug, because the request is generated by flash.  That is why i suggested: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/  so you could see the actual php response

Comment: Ok I get you now, ill let you guys know what I find!

Comment: Ok, well fiddler reports the following on a successful upload:

3




1
1
0

which is bizarre because I thought it was only supposed to return a 1 !

Comment: right ive done some fiddling and the result is that when a file hangs the server returns exactly the same reponse as it did for all the files that completed succesfully:

3 1 1 0 

Any comments much appreciated :)

Comment: Matty, confirm that your event handers have been declared without inverted commas? I found that Uploadify evens would only sometimes fire if they were declared with `'onComplete': function(event...` - removing inverted commas seems to fix the problem

Comment: Hi Jimbo, they have been declared with commas yes, I will remove them and let you know the outcome.

Thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Simply add `echo "astlavista babi"` to your uploadify script, this echo statement should be the last line, if you have conditional statement then echo should be placed as a last line within the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I would take, in order:

1) Be 100% certain you are getting a 200 response from your server.  If not, that is the problem

2) Use the latest and the greatest uplaodify and jquery

3) Check for JS errors (firebug console or browser JS debugger will work)

4) Upgrade your Flash player (if that solves it then you can require a higher version)

5) Put a debug statements in the uploadify source, specifically in the complete handler to be sure it gets called

6) If the progress is reaching 100% but the handler never gets called, I'm afraid the next step may be to dive into the actionscript and use the debugger or some trace statements to figure out where the error is.  This can mean that there is a bug in calling the external interface function

7) If you make fixes, submit back to uploadify

Answer (score 0):

Chreck your `php.ini` file for `post_max_size` parameter. It must be >= `upload_max_filesize` parameter. For more details see http://php.net/post-max-size.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I had this problem when sending data to the upload script using "scriptData" and solved it by simply echoing "ok" in the upload script rather than sending back an empty document.

Comment: The problem with that I've found is that it then thinks the file completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using Macs use [HTTP Scoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/index.html) to view the request as Firebug does not show it. More on HTTP Scoop from [this blog](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/04/03/monitoring-http-traffic-to-debug-your-grails-application/).