# Disable render process in lithium

Tags: php, uploadify, lithium

i use uploadify for my upload process. The problem is that after each upload lithium tries to render the view of the controller. In my case uploadify.html.php. How can i disable this behaviour and just return a 200 OK.

My controller code:

```
class UploadController extends \app\controllers\AppController {

public function index() {}

public function uploadify() {
    Logger::write('info', 'start upload');

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $fileData = $this->request->data['Filedata'];
        $error = $fileData['error'];
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            // everything ok
            $tempFile = $fileData['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = $this->request->env('DOCUMENT_ROOT') . $fileData['folder'] . '/';
            $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $fileData['name'];
            move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
            Logger::write('info', 'upload file successfull to ' . $targetFile);
        } else if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE || $error == UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE) {
            // file size to large
            Logger::write('error', 'file to large ' . $fileData['Filename']);
        } else if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL) {
            // only partial uplopad
            Logger::write('error', 'uploaded partial ' . $fileData['Filename']);
        } else if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
            // no file uploaded
            Logger::write('error', 'couldn\'t upload ' . $fileData['Filename']);
        } else {
            Logger::write('error', 'Unknown error code ' . $error);
        }
    } else {
        Logger::write('error', 'no form data');
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To only renders the headers of the response, not the body, set

```
$this->render(array('head' => true))
```

Same with `redirect()`

Docs: http://li3.me/docs/lithium/action/Controller::render

Comment: for uploadify its important to return something -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399654/oncomplete-and-oncompleteall-events-failing-to-fire-when-using-uploadify

Answer (score 0):

You can go about this in one of two ways.

The first approach is turning off auto rendering:

```
class MyController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
  public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
    $defaults = array('render' => array('auto' => false));
    return parent::__construct($config + $defaults);
  }
}
```

The second approach would be to use "content-type negotiation" by sending a [HTTP Accepts header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html):

```
class MyController extends \lithium\action\Controller {
  public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
    $defaults = array('render' => array('negotiate' => true));
    return parent::__construct($config + $defaults);
  }
}
```

You can read more about how to configure how the controller renders [here](http://li3.me/docs/lithium/action/Controller%3a%3a%24_render).

Comment: thx, but this works only for the whole class. i have other methods which needs the render process. if there is something method based? If not i have to create an other Controller.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you just need to add following line to your controller action:

```
$this->_render['head'] = true;
```